# KRL: Replace HASH val

Tags: krl

I can see plenty of example of how to read from a hash or add to a hash (using put), but how do I replace a current value? Any simple examples would be cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked much with hashes, but you might look at Mike Grace's example here:

http://kynetxappaday.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/day-28-updating-users-list-when-user-joins-app/

That will replace the entire hash. I'm not sure how to replace just one value in the hash.